Can I apply for a new Indian e-visa if my previous e-visa has not expired?
My current one-year e-visa tourist to India is valid till the end of August 24. I am not in India currently.

If I apply for a new (5-years) tourist e-visa in the beginning of August 24, is it likely to be rejected just because my previous visa is still valid?
If a visa is rejected for this reason, will it affect my chances of getting a new visa after my current one expires?


What are you trying to accomplish by applying for the visa early? As far as I understand, both the 1 and 5 year visas limit you to 180 days per year in India, getting a new visa will not reset this. The visa also only has to be valid at the time of entry into India.

@lambshaanxy  I am flying to India around September 15th 2024.  I'd rather not wait till the end of August and order a new visa only then, but order it ahead of time (to be on the safe side).

I have tried and applied for a new Indian e-visa on August 2nd 2024, while still having a valid Indian e-visa  that expires on August 18th 2024. I have applied for a 5-years e-visa (the previous one being for one year).
The request was successful, and I have received a new e-visa.

You can apply for a new Indian e-visa even if your current one has not yet expired, but it is possible that the application may be rejected due to the existing valid visa. If a visa is rejected for this reason, it typically won't affect your chances of obtaining a new visa after your current one expires, as long as all other requirements are met.
